# Create trigger to insert After Update the table

Tags: oracle, triggers

Create a trigger named `trigger_contact_af_update` that is triggered whenever the `contact` table is updated. This trigger will insert the org_name and action into the table `contact_log_history` after the update of contact details. The action name in the affected log table `contact_log_history` is `'After_Update_Contact'`.

Hints:

- Trigger name : trigger_contact_af_update
- Table name : contact_log_history
- Field names : org_name,action
- Action  : 'After_Update_Contact'.

The table structure of `contact_log_history` is as follows:

```
org_name Varchar(30)
action Varchar(30)
```

I wrote the below trigger but no error or trigger created.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_contact_af_update AFTER UPDATE 
    ON contact_log_history FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    org_name VARCHAR(30);
    action VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN 
    if (:new.action == 'After_Update_Contact') 
    then 
        INSERT INTO contact_log_history (org_name, action) 
        values (:new.org_name, :new:action);
    end if ;
END;
```

Comment: Your assignment says to track changes in the `contact` table but for some reason you have built the trigger on  `contact_log_history`. You might get more success if you built it on the right table.

Comment: and replace double equation (`==`)  with single(`=`) for `:new.action == 'After_Update_Contact'`

Comment: Tried the below, but still trigger is not created.                  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  contact_af_update AFTER UPDATE 
    ON contact FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    org_name VARCHAR(30);
    action VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN 
    if (:new.action = 'After_Update_Contact') 
    then 
        INSERT INTO contact_log_history (org_name, action) 
        values (:new.org_name, :new:action);
    end if ;
END;

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SHOW ERRORS
```

or

`select * from user_errors;`

to check the errors during compilation for procedures/functions/triggers.

Here's a working trigger after fixing the issues and avoiding the variables.

```
CREATE  OR replace TRIGGER contact_af_update AFTER 
UPDATE 
ON contact FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
BEGIN 
  IF (:new.action = 'After_Update_Contact') THEN 
    INSERT INTO contact_log_history 
                ( 
                            org_name, 
                            action 
                ) 
                VALUES 
                ( 
                            :new.org_name, 
                            :new.action 
                ); 

  END IF ; 
END;
/
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3d715364741cba7982780b7cb9c841bd)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
CREATE  OR replace TRIGGER trigger_contact_af_update AFTER 
UPDATE 
ON contact FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
 
    INSERT INTO contact_log_history 
                ( 
                            org_name, 
                            action 
                ) 
                VALUES 
                ( 
                            :new.org_name, 
                            'After_Update_Contact' 
                ); 

  
END trigger_contact_af_update;
/
```

Comment: What's the benefit of this approach compared to [@Kaushik Nayak's similar code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128926/3025856) from three years ago?